# Flutter - First screen gets corrupted only on real iOS devices, not Android and not on simulator

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

The problem arises when a user opens the app and after launch screen, the app's own splash screen starts.

Instead of a normal loading screen like on Android, it paints all the characters as blocks and shows a progressive mirroring effect with the screen repainting smaller and smaller ad infinitum like background.

https://ibb.co/m6K3YCQ

I've tried deploy app to IOS Simulator everything works normally.

My Dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
      sdk: flutter
  http: ^0.12.0+1
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.1+2
  transparent_image: ^1.0.0
  photo_view: ^0.2.2
  cached_network_image: ^0.7.0
  firebase_admob: ^0.8.0+3
  connectivity: ^0.4.2
  flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.3.4
```

My Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:transparent_image/transparent_image.dart';
import 'package:technokids_gallery/app/utils/Network.dart';
import 'package:technokids_gallery/app/models/mainCategories.dart';
import 'package:technokids_gallery/app/pages/subCategory.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  static final String routeName = 'home';

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _HomePageState();
  }
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  var _page = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    NetworkUtils.checkConnectivity(_scaffoldKey);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /* final double barHeight = 20.0;
    final double statusbarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top; */

    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar: PreferredSize(
        preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(40.0),
        child: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            'TECHNOKIDS GALLERY',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 22.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              letterSpacing: 0,
            ),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          elevation: 0,
          flexibleSpace: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                colors: [Color(0xFF0D47A1), Color(0xFF1976D2)],
                begin: const FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
                end: const FractionalOffset(0.4, 0.9),
                stops: [0.0, 1.0],
                tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: PageView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Offstage(
              offstage: _page != 0,
              child: TickerMode(
                enabled: _page == 0,
                child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: getMainCategories(),
                  builder:
                      (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List> snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData)
                      return Container(
                        child: Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            strokeWidth: 3.0,
                            valueColor:
                                AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.orange),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    List mainCats = snapshot.data;
                    return CustomScrollView(
                      primary: true,
                      slivers: <Widget>[
                        SliverPadding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          sliver: SliverGrid.count(
                            crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
                            childAspectRatio: 1.35,
                            mainAxisSpacing: 8,
                            crossAxisCount: 2,
                            children:
                                createMainCategoryCardItem(mainCats, context),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> createMainCategoryCardItem(
      List<MainCategories> maincats, BuildContext context) {
    // Children list for the list.
    List<Widget> listElementWidgetList = List<Widget>();

    if (maincats != null) {
      var lengthOfList = maincats.length;

      for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfList; i++) {
        MainCategories maincat = maincats[i];
        // Image URL        
        var imageURL =
            "http://10.0.3.2:8081/gallery/sections/" + maincat.sectionPhoto;
        // List item created with an image of the poster
        var listItem = GridTile(
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              if (maincat.id != "0") {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (_) => SubCategoryPage(maincat.id),
                  ),
                );
              }
            },
            child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
              placeholder: kTransparentImage,
              image: imageURL,
            ),
          ),
        );

        listElementWidgetList.add(listItem);
      }
    }
    return listElementWidgetList;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming it's because you're not using the Scaffold widget to wrap your application. The PageView widget cannot understand what dimensions you want to it to take, thus crashing the app.

Comment: Maybe you are correct for PageView widget. I think scrolling my gallery in that widget. But it's working different for thing. I will change my code and I will try again today. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem. My problem is FadeInImage.

```
child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
         placeholder: kTransparentImage,
         image: imageURL,
         fit: BoxFit.contain,
),

to

child: CachedNetworkImage(
         imageUrl: imageURL,
         fit: BoxFit.contain,
       errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(
          Icons.error,
           color: Colors.red,
           ),
),
```